# How to change div class on click event?

Tags: php, javascript, zend-framework

i have a head layout and some image on it. I need to change the image on click event.
for this i am using **javascript**.

```
function changebrouse()
{
document.getElementById("browse").className = "browse";
return false;

}
```

with the help of this js image can change but on click, page refresh and previous image will appear.

```
<div id="browse" class="sections_browser"><a href="<?php echo $this->url(
                            array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'search'),
                            'default',
                            true) ?>" onclick='changebrouse()'></a></div>
```

**css**

```
.sections_browser a
{
    width:72px;
    height:31px;
    float:left;
    background-image:url(../images/button/browse_dwn.png);
}

.browse a
{
    width:72px;
    height:31px;
    float:left;
    background-image:url(../images/button/browse_hover.png);
}
```

please help . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure why someone gave -1, unclear questions are the norm here... anyway, you set to class "browser" but the two css classes you post are "sections_browser" and "browse". ??? (In addition to the return thing someone correctly pointed out just now) ... oh, someone corrected the -1, nice.

Comment: this is not about unclear question or what, simply OP too lazy to do a search...this should be discourage

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

`onclick='changebrouse()'`

to

`onclick='return changebrouse()'`

And in the 'changebrouse' function, the class name should be 'browse' not 'browser', I think.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel the click event. Change on your onclick to be:

```
< ... onclick="changebrouse(); return false;">
```

returning false will signal to the browser to ignore the click.

Comment: Thanks for your precious advice. It works according to you but in my case when i need to return click again on first image( button ) after clicking second, it dosen't work. it should be. Thanks again.

Comment: Returning false from an onclick doesn't permanently disable clicks on that button - it just stops the current click from being acted on. if another button stops working, then there's something else wrong. I'd suggest looking at your javascript console (shift-ctrl-j in firefox) and look for JS errors.